# "Invalid left-hand side in assignment" when receiving response from Facebook API

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get an extended access token for one of my apps using the Javascript API (I know I should do this server side, but I'm the only one using this app and I have some reasons for not doing it server side this time)

Anyway, when I receive a call back from Facebook, I get an Invalid left-hand side in assignment error.

I don't have any weird if's or anything like that and it only happens when I get the response back from Facebook - so it has nothing to do with the code I've written I don't think.

Anyway, here's the itty-bitty script I'm running.

```
var token = response.authResponse.accessToken;

FB.api(
    '/oauth/access_token',
    'GET',
    {
        'grant_type': 'fb_exchange_token',
        'client_id': 'XXX',
        'client_secret': 'XXX',
        'fb_exchange_token': token
    },
    function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
);
```

My token variable is set correctly, so that's not the issue.

If I remove any of the data sent in the array, I get an expected error response, but with it set up this way I just get that error mentioned above and this response from Facebook.

```
Object {error: Object} 
error: Objectmessage: "unknown error"
type: "http"
```

So I'm kind of stumped on this.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Is that the actual code?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly it, minus my app id and secret.

Comment: I'm getting my token from the login request, which works fine, but when I pass it through to this function here, that's when I get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up with.

Not ideal as it doesn't use the Faceook SDK, but it works.

```
$.get('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token', {
    'grant_type': 'fb_exchange_token',
    'client_id': 'XXX',
    'client_secret': 'XXX',
    'fb_exchange_token': token
}).done(function(data) {
    var response = data.split('&');
    var result = {};

    for (i=0;i<response.length;i++) {
        var this_one = response[i].split("=");
        result[this_one[0]] = this_one[1];
    }

    console.log(result);

});
```

This ends up with an object with the token and expiration time.